# Is it possible to make a key act as “upper-case character backwards”?

Tags: linux, keyboard, xorg

We all know `⌫`, also known as “backspace” or “delete character backwards” (to the left). I would like a key like that, only it either:

1. Switches the case of the character to the left.
2. Makes it upper-case.

The reason I want a key for this and not just a shortcut is that it should work across applications without having to configure them. It’s enough for it to work in graphical applications running under X11; it doesn’t have to work in things like terminals.

Is this something that can be solved in X11?

## Motivation

I would like to see if I can replace my use of the shift keys with this approach, as well as more application-dependent functionality for e.g. capitalising whole words, title casing sentences, and so on. While I could perhaps get the whole job done with application-dependent functions and shortcuts, there are always going to be text entry in text boxes and forms. So I still need some generic way to make characters upper-case in any situation, and a key like this would perhaps be sufficient.

Comment: You'd need some sort of script that is able to interface with whatever program you currently use to find out what exact letter you want to replace at the time of pressing the key, so I'd say your chances are pretty low to actually get this working.

Comment: There are several tools that allow for e.g. japanese input by converting hiragana to kanji, like `ibus` or `anthy`. You'd need something similar for your "uppercase-postfix", so maybe they can be hacked to allow to do something like this. But it's still a non-trivial amount of work, and may not be usable everywhere.